# Godaddy SSL certificate isn't working on ubuntu 14.04 + apache server

Tags: 14.04, apache2, amazon-ec2, openssl

I have an SSL certificate from Godaddy, I finished the first steps for generating the keys and submitting the CSR and I'm trying to install the certificate on my Apache server. I followed the steps in these links:
https://www.codingepiphany.com/2014/11/26/installing-godaddy-ssl-certificate-in-an-ubuntu-server/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority

But it doesn't work, the website redirects to https but it's unreachable. 
The server is hosted on Amazon server.
I checked my certificate on Godaddy CSR decoder, The data of the website is correct.

**Any help is appreciated!**

Here is my virtual host xyz.conf configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.xyz.com

    ServerAlias xyz.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/c4*******6.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/xyz.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-****.crt

    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xyz/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: please check if apache has a ``Listen *:443`` or similar somewhere in its configuration (usually in ``/etc/apache2/ports.conf`` or ``/etc/apache2/listen.conf``).
Then see if apache2 is really listening on port 443: ``netstat -tapenl | grep apache``

Comment: Hi Philip, Thanks for your help.
I have these lines in ports.conf
 <IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

Comment: Should I add it like: Listen 443 ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was with Amazon EC2 not Apache.
The 443 should be enabled from EC2 dashboard. It was a bit confusing because the Apache was already listening on port 443.